# Is it possibile to return a value from child function if it runs into some condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering whether it is possible to return value from function if some function which is called by the caller function run into some condition, but without any conditioning in the caller function.
It sounds a bit messy, so I will try to give an example.

```
def called_function(number):
    number += 29
    if number % 10 == 0:
         return False     # This returns False straight to total_of_vals variable
    return number         # This should work without if condition in caller function


def caller_function(number_list):
    total = 0
    for number in number_list:
        number = called_function(number)
        if number is False:    # This condition to be removed
            return number
        total += number

    return total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    total_of_vals = caller_function([5, 23, 23, 41, 4])
    if total_of_vals is False:
        print('Some error occurred')
    print(f'TOTAL : {total_of_vals}')
```

This is an example calculation and using if conditions is alright, however when there is a wider range of functions which call each other, returning from some function requires to add if statements in every caller function.

Is there any way to force python to return that False value straightly from any called function?

Comment: You can let the value bubble up by raising an Exception, but I wouldn't consider it good form.

Comment: you can use `raise` to escalation result from sub-function to outside function

Comment: I don't think there is, but is always hard to prove that something doesn't exist. Just as a suggestion I would never do code like this, specially for big projects, it would be hell to read the functions and understand what is going on. Your called function in this example is doing two things, checking a condition or doing an operation, it would make sense to do one function that only checks the condition and other that only do the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the example to use `raise` instead of `return False`

```py
def called_function(number):
    number += 29
    if number % 10 == 0:
         raise ValueError(f'{number} is invalid')
    return number


def caller_function(number_list):
    total = 0
    for number in number_list:
        number = called_function(number)
        total += number

    return total


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        total_of_vals = caller_function([5, 23, 23, 41, 4])
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f'Some error occurred: {e}')
    else:
        print(f'TOTAL : {total_of_vals}')
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what is supposed to be used here :)